# Async in reduce

Tags: javascript

Not sure why the following code is not working

```
const pPipe = async (x, ...fns) => fns.reduce(async (v, f) => await f(v), x);
const add1 = async (current) => current + 1;

(async () => {
    // should print 11
    console.log(await add1(10));
    // And it does

    // Should print 3
    console.log(await pPipe(1, add1, add1))
    // And it does not :(
})();
```

This prints `[object Promise]1`. Not sure why the object promise is being returned and not the addition?

Comment: Because `v` is a promise, and you're adding `1` to that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your `reduce` callback is async, the accumulator `v` will become a promise in the second call of the `reduce` callback, and following calls. So you are then passing a *promise* to `f`.

To make sure you pass the actual *value*, you need to await that promise (`await v`). On the other hand, it is not necessary to use `await` for what is returned in an `async` function, so you can leave out `await` from before the `f` call:

```
const pPipe = async (x, ...fns) => 
    fns.reduce(async (v, f) => f(await v), x);
```

```js
const pPipe = async (x, ...fns) => fns.reduce(async (v, f) => f(await v), x);
const add1 = async (current) => current + 1;

(async () => {
    console.log(await add1(10)); // 11
    console.log(await pPipe(1, add1, add1)) // 3
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

`reduce` is not async aware.

The async function you pass to it returns a promise, so `reduce` uses the *promise* (and not the result of resolving the promise) as the accumulated value.

Use a `for` loop if you need to `await` in a loop.